# How does this arm64 instruction allocate enough space on the stack for 2 register values?

Tags: arm64

I am referring to this ARM64 documentation: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102374/0101/Loads-and-stores---load-pair-and-store-pair

It has this instruction:

```
STP        X0, X1, [SP, #-16]!
```

The description is:

```
Load and store pair instructions are often used for pushing, and popping off the stack.
This first instruction pushes X0 and X1 onto the stack
```

If these registers in arm64 are 128-bits (16 bytes), I assume we'd need 32 bytes total to store 2 of them on the stack, but the instruction above only subtracts 16 bytes from the stack pointer.

I must be misunderstanding the `SP, #-16`. Does this actually make enough space for the 2 registers to be copied in?

Comment: The general-purpose X registers are 64 bits, not 128, so everything fits.  You might be thinking of the SIMD registers (V or Q) which are 128 bits.

Comment: You're right, that was my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general purpose registers are 64-bits (not 128-bits as mentioned in the question), so allocating 16 bytes on the stack does fit the x0 and x1 registers.